# Error loading type library/DLL when I try to add file in VS (HRESULT: 0x80029C4A)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a trouble when I try to create a view in my web project.

Here is my error message:

```
There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))'
```

I've already checked other response. If I run as admin or none, same issue. I have another computer that hasn't this error with same OS + VS. If there is something to copy, I can do it.

I don't find this exception in event viewer to see details (how?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally fixed this by using repair tool of Visual Studio.

For people that repair will not help, this is compiled things I've read to fix this issue:

1. Reset via CLI VS settings: vswindexpress /resetuserdata - [geoffwebbercross blogpost](http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.lu/2014/05/resetting-visual-studio-express-2013.html)
2. Reset via Doc/AppSettings and regedit
3. Rebuild the project, restart VS, restart computer
4. Repair VS (this fixes my issue) [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983433(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: The hardest but the one that saves me too

Answer (score 0):

I simply went to Add or remove programs in control panel. Repaired my visual studio from there and this worked for me like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same error after I installed .Net Core 1.1 from official web site. I did repair of VS(2015 Upd5) and it did not help. Then I uninstalled .Net Core and repaired VS and finally it started working normally.

Update: I also uninstalled Entity Framework 6.x (from Programs and Features)