# Issue when adding Controller using "Add scaffold" wizard in VS Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2, vs-community-edition

Need your help! I have tried other responses from different posts nothing worked f me.
So posting my issue here.

When adding "**`Web API 2 controller - Empty`**" using "**`Add Scaffold`**" wizard:

[image]

I'm getting this issue.

> There was an error running the selected code generator Error loading type library/DLL (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

[image: Issue]

Comment: hi please go through this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454956/error-loading-type-library-dll-when-i-try-to-add-file-in-vs-hresult-0x80029c4a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error loading type library/DLL when I try to add file in VS (HRESULT: 0x80029C4A)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454956/error-loading-type-library-dll-when-i-try-to-add-file-in-vs-hresult-0x80029c4a)

Comment: Issue may be duplicate but any of the solutions provided in the previous post didn't worked for me.. with the same environment in another system I didn't face this issue. Windows7 machine got an issue. Windows10 machine working fine. Except OS rest of all same in both systems. Anyway I'm trying to uninstall and install VS, frameworks everything and will try again.